# Was this reopen audit question actually a good post?

Tags: discussion, review, closed-questions, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Okay, sadly enough I've failed yet another review audit - this time in the reopen queue. Okay, yes I was/am new to the reopen queue, and this time in fact I've clicked "Skip" a hell of a lot more than in the other 4 queues that need less reputation (close votes are also very subjective and require a lot of skipping). This time, [the following post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/3256198) tripped me up:

[image]

Now for most close/reopen posts, I would have clicked "skip" and moved on. However, for this example I thought it was relatively clear cut in it being closed. My rationale for leaving it closed:

- the question does not make clear what was the issue with the application crashing on startup
- it does not provide any relevant information as to what was the particular issue surrounding the change in the Java version that requires a fix
- warning messages from the control panel (that the questioner said was able to be removed by setting a directive in the manifest) were not shown, so a decision of what to do could not be made clearly and easily

So, I have now three questions:

1. Is this a fair review audit?
2. Do you think that my rationale was a reasonable way of thinking or not?
3. Is this (overall) a reasonable question to open, and was I wrong to leave the question closed (if it was actually closed in the first place)?

Comment: Myeah, I interpret those upvotes more as a "yeah, damn thing started to act up for me as well" rather than a "great question".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, this was kind of a crap audit. I would've probably skipped it (or opened it in a separate tab to check the answers and thus realized it was an audit) - it *might* be missing critical information, or it might be a perfectly understandable issue to someone familiar with the topic; heck, it might be a bug report - I really don't know *anything* about Web Start or SWT.
2. They're reasonable criticisms, but... Like I said, I would've skipped it since I honestly have *no* idea if the omissions are damning or simply omitted because they're trivially obvious to anyone familiar with the platform. That doesn't make your decision process wrong; it just makes it a crap audit since you might've failed it by knowing *too much* about the topic.
3. If I found this question closed, I would perhaps leave a comment for the author requesting further details, but wouldn't re-open unless I observed significant support from folks who actually understood the question (IOW, this is one of those icky situations where a really good answer might be enough to warrant keeping a fairly lazy question around).